# Effects of Application pool recycling on worker process and WebEventProvider

Tags: asp.net

I have a WebEventProvider in my project to do some background porcess at fixed intervals. 
As I see, it stops when application pool is recycled and does not restart automatically. According to logs, Application_End event is called more than one times but Application_Start event is not called. Does it mean that application is not restarted automatically after application pool recycling? Does recycling worker processes have anything to do with WebEventProvider?

Comment: This is why you don't want to have periodic code running as part of an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to use a different mechanism if you want have cleanup and other timed events run on your server. IIS is simply not meant for that.

You should consider moving all of these events to a scheduled task with a console application, or something similar.

However, if you absolutely need to run these within the running IIS process, you can setup a scheduled task to run tinyget.exe, which is part of the [IIS resource kit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840671), to request a page at certain intervals. This will insure your IIS process is properly running before your other tasks need to fire.

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET Health Monitoring configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fwh2ss9.aspx) is part of ASP.NET settings schema - indicating that it must be provided by ASP.NET run-time. Now app-pool is really a worker process(es) launched by IIS and recycle of app-pool will not start ASP.NET application. Unless ASP.NET application is triggered, ASP.NET runtime will not come into the picture.

I believe that you need to look at [auto-starting your ASP.NET application](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) - unfortunately, its only IIS 7.5 feature. Another way is to set-up scheduler to ping your application (send a dummy request) periodically.

Comment: Can i assume that when application pool and worker process are recycled, ASP.NET application is also stopped and its would not be restarted unless something restarts it automatically or a user makes a request?

Comment: @PyaePhyoAung, in general, that's correct assumption. More strictly speaking, app-pool recycle corresponds to ASP.NET application shutdown on **that machine**. (Also, one app-pool may have multiple worker processes and worker process recycle may not impact particular ASP.NET application)

Comment: another intriguing thing is that I log application events such as Application_Start and Application_End from Global.asax.vb. According to the log file, during application pool recycling, Application_End event is sometimes called two or three times. I am not sure if this behaviour is because of the worker processes that are recycled one after another. It would be really helpful if you can tell me about that.

Comment: @PyaePhyoAung, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx Application_End should get fired only once per application per app-domain. So only possibility that I think is that you have multiple .NET applications using the same application pool.

Comment: I got it. I have two same applications: I mean sharing same physical project. But, they are used by two different sites.Yet, when the application pool is recycled, both of them will be ended. I think that's why Application_End event is called multiple times and sometimes Application_Start event is not called but request can hit.( I use log4Net to log from the Application_Start and _End handlers.) But could you please tell how I can differentiate this two applications. Is there something like App ID? That might help me keep track of which one is started or ended. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PyaePhyoAung, there is no built-in id. But you can always create your own unique id (say `Guid.New`) in `Application_Start` and store it in application state or static variable. You can probably use the root url of your site as your identifier. And finally, you you can lways log into different logs files (using config).

Comment: I have tried to differentiate two same applications under the same application pool by using HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath. I log the application events from both applications to the single physical file. What I have found is that if I made requests first to the application A, only the succeeding events to the application A are logged. That happens the same to the application B if it is requested in the first place. Furthermore, often, Application_End event is called twice for one application when application pool is recycled (as i can see the url). Is that normal?